# I Got the XML data ,Now how I can save the XML Data in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xml

As an New to the iOS Development in Xcode 7.
Below I have some questions please clarify my doubt.

1. I need to Store the XML Data from an URL
2. And Split the XML data each line and store it in the Objective C.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <NewDataSet>
   <tbl>
       <Es_Id>8e268283-e87e-4abc-aab9-07cb611a8e60</Es_Id>
       <EstablishmentType>40640054-2221-4086-92e4-4440497ccea2</EstablishmentType>
       <EstablishmentName>La Parrilla Colombian Steakhouse &amp; Bar</EstablishmentName>
       <BusinessName>La Parrilla Colombian Steakhouse &amp; Bar</BusinessName>
       <OpenTime>PT8H31M</OpenTime>
       <ClosingTime>PT18H50M</ClosingTime>
       <Floor>12 th floor</Floor>
   </tbl>
   </NewDataSet>`

Comment: What are you looking exactly?  Provide XML data structure and code you written.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara This my XML data Sir... I need this Xml Data to store in Objective- C

<NewDataSet>
  <tbl>
    <Es_Id>8e268283-e87e-4abc-aab9-07cb611a8e60</Es_Id>
    <EstablishmentType>40640054-2221-4086-92e4-4440497ccea2</EstablishmentType>
    <EstablishmentName>La Parrilla Colombian Steakhouse &amp; Bar</EstablishmentName>
    <BusinessName>La Parrilla Colombian Steakhouse &amp; Bar</BusinessName>
    <OpenTime>PT8H31M</OpenTime>
    <ClosingTime>PT18H50M</ClosingTime>
    <Floor>12 th floor</Floor>

Comment: Put it in your question with proper format, so one can easily underastand.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara i have got the XML data from url and i need to store the XML data in Objective c. Can u help me

Comment: You can refer [this tutorial by AppGuruz](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xmlparsing-with-nsxmlparser-tutorial) for XML parsing. You can do it easily with help of it.

Comment: Thank you @DipenPanchasara.

Comment: Arunkumar Vijaykumar check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I start learning XML parsing it has basic steps.I implement all for you.

In ViewController.h

**Step 1 : Add the Delegate classes**

```
First you have to add <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

**Step 2 : Create necessary objects**

```
NSXMLParser *parser;
NSMutableData *ReceviedData;
NSMutableString *currentStringValue;
NSMutableArray *arrayID;
```

Now it looks like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
  NSXMLParser *parser;
  NSMutableData *ReceviedData;
  NSMutableString *currentStringValue;
  NSMutableArray *arrayID;
}
@end
```

Then in ViewController.m

**Step 3 - Allocate your Array in your viewDidLoad method**

```
arrayID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

**Step 4 - Create Connection in your viewDidLoad Like**

```
[self createConnection:@"http://www.google.com"]; //give your valid url.
```

Now  the viewDidLoad method is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   arrayID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [self createConnection:@"http://www.google.com"]; //give your valid url.
}
```

createConnection method is

```
-(void)createConnection:(NSString *)urlString
{
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    // Step 5 - parser delegate methods are using NSURLConnectionDelegate class or not.
    BOOL success;
    if (!parser)
    {
      parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
      parser.delegate = self;
      parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = YES;
      success = [parser parse];
      NSLog(@"Success : %c",success);
    }
}
```

**STEP 6 - NSXMLParserDlegate Methods are below**

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"Current Element Name : %@",elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ID"])  //according to your xml response your id is Es_Id.So you need to compare @"Es_Id"
    {
         NSLog(@"The Result is==%@",elementName);
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Current String Value : %@",currentStringValue);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ID"]) //according to your xml response your id is Es_Id.So you need to compare @"Es_Id"
    {
       [arrayResult addObject:currentStringValue];
    }
       currentStringValue = nil;
}
```

From above code I check ID only.According to your response you need to compare other keys like  EstablishmentType,EstablishmentName,BusinessName,OpenTime.......